# Get ExceptionInInitializerError when adding json-schema-validator to android test project

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to add [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) to my android test project using gradle but I runs into some problems:

1. File duplication in `json-schema-validator` and `json-schema-core` prevented me to build test project so I excluded them in `packagingOptions`
2. File not found when running tests: While running android test, I got the exception at

   JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();

My guess is JsonLoader could not locate /draftv4/schema in test project

Any one successfully added it to android test or how help JsonLoader get correct file.
Thanks

### Here are the build script and exception stacktrace

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'APK META-INF/ASL-2.0.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL-2.0.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL-3.0.txt'
        exclude 'ASL-2.0.txt'
        exclude 'LGPL-3.0.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'draftv3/schema'
        exclude 'draftv4/schema'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportMode true

        testApplicationId "com.sample.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            zipAlign false
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    // Other dependencies

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:3.8'
    androidTestCompile ("com.github.fge:json-schema-core:1.2.3");
    androidTestCompile ('com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:2.1.8')
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}
```

---

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<init>(SchemaVersion.java:65)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<clinit>(SchemaVersion.java:44)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfigurationBuilder.<init>(LoadingConfigurationBuilder.java:117)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.configuration.LoadingConfiguration.byDefault(LoadingConfiguration.java:151)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.<init>(JsonSchemaFactoryBuilder.java:66)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder(JsonSchemaFactory.java:120)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault(JsonSchemaFactory.java:110)
at com.chatwing.managers.ApiManagerImplTest.assertRegisterValidationError(ApiManagerImplTest.java:115)
at com.chatwing.managers.ApiManagerImplTest.testRegisterChatWingWithDuplicateEmail(ApiManagerImplTest.java:191)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: resource /draftv4/schema not found
at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.fromResource(JsonLoader.java:91)
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.<init>(SchemaVersion.java:63)
... 21 more
```

Answer (score 2):

From Gradle 0.9.1 the following is supported:

```
android.packagingOptions {
    pickFirst '/draftv4/schema'
}
```

More information in the [Gradle release note](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)s.

Comment: This helped me. I remove "exclude 'draftv3/schema'" & "exclude 'draftv4/schema'", add "pickFirst '/draftv4/schema'" & "pickFirst '/draftv3/schema'", now the "JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault()" initialization is successful. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround for my own question.

The reason `/draftv4/schema` was missing is because I excluded them as suggested. I thought it will keep one version of them but it seems no `/draftv4/schema` in the project.

So I cloned `json-schema-core` and remove manually `/draftv4/schema` and `/draftv3/schema`. 
I also remove exclusion for those files in main gradle build. Then everything is fine.

I still can't accept this answer since it's still a workaround. Is there any better way to exclude those files in build.gradle?

Comment: Hello, library author here; why don't you just include json-schema-validator? The dependency mechanism will pull -core anyway

Comment: But I encounter duplication exception while building it. I have to clone `json-schema-core` and remove duplicated files and the build and tests are happy

Comment: @CuongThai Probably a bit smaller workaround setting the thread's contextclassloader to the core's classloader (``SchemaVersion.class.getClassLoader()` for example). See https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/issues/111#issuecomment-57469591 for a related example.

Comment: @fge any news on this being resolved? My implementation does not allow me to solve the issue in the way that the OP did...